# How can I split same-project unit tests into separate assemblies?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, teamcity

I have a few test projects, one of which has *many* unit tests, all very related to doing certain calculations. Running *all* unit tests takes a long time. So, I'm looking for a way to easily split tests into **nightly** unit tests and *all other* unit tests. How can I conveniently specify which test fixtures and test methods should be **nightly**? In other words, **is there a way to split tests from within the same project into separate assemblies**?

What I've thought of and tried so far:

- Just separate the nightly tests into their own project manually and only run that new project on a nightly basis. *This would mean moving files around in the project anytime I wanted to make a test fixture run nightly or regularly, i.e. not desirable.*
- Come up with a build script that separates these tests at compile time into separate projects. Then I'd end up with separate assemblies. This seems too complicated, but maybe it's the only option.

I would love to be able to use a class attribute to specify which tests will run nightly, e.g.:

```
[TestClass, Nightly]
public class MyTestClass { }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have as many unit test projects for the same solution as you need.

If you want to go with separate project (i.e. your build system only setup to run test from separate project) I'd have new project *sharing* tests from old one - create new project and add files from old one as "link" (there is small option on "Open" button of add file dialog to do so).

Alternatively you can add attributes to tests (i.e. [TestCategoryAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcategoryattribute.aspx)) and make your test runner respect those.

Comment: The `TestCategoryAttribute` looks promising. Is this any way to apply that on the Test Class level, so that all Test Methods for that class get the category applied?

Comment: @William - no, it is marked as "target=method" (see MSDN link). I don't know what teamcity runner allows, but maybe you can create custom attributes and filter on those or just by test name/class name.